# A function that creates a function with parameters

Tags: python, function, parameters

I am writing a function that will take a sequence of strings as a parameter, and then return a function (probably a lambda) where those strings are the names of the parameters. I can make it return a function, but I can't quite figure out how to set the parameters of the returned function.

i.e. if I gave called `make_a_new_function(('a','b','c','d'))` the returned function would have four parameters: a, b, c and d.

I know that the `function.__code__.co_varnames` is stored as a tuple of strings, but it's a read-only value so I can't edit it.

Is what I'm wanting possible? Or am I going mad over impossible dreams?

EDIT: Turns out there was a good alternative by constructing a string of python syntax, then using `eval()` to call the expression.

Comment: Why do you need to dynamically create a new function, instead of creating one function which accepts `*args` and/or `**kwargs`?

Comment: You'd probably have to use something like `exec` here, but this totally sounds like the X-Y problem.

Comment: What is this new function supposed to *do* using these parameters? What is the source of the code that does that? I agree this might be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @deceze I'm writing code that will create a logical expression out of a truth table. I can do it using strings, but I'd like it to be an actual python expression if I can. i.e. something that I can call rather than just look at.

Comment: That's a high level task description and not sufficient to explain why you think *this* is the way to implement that.

Comment: So I have a whole bunch of binary numbers as strings, representing the possible inputs to this logic circuit, and then I have a matching list of booleans, representing the resulting outputs from the input. My thinking was that I would, for each true input, create an expression representing an AND gate for that input state and return that expression. e.g. if for a circuit with ABCD inputs, '1101' was true, it would give `A and B and (not C) and D` as a function.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Oh so it looks like exec may not help me, but eval might. If I make it return my expressions as strings of python-correct code, I can use eval on that to actually evaluate it.

Comment: There are likely much simpler ways to achieve whatever it is you want to achieve; `functools.update_wrapper` comes to mind, or a custom class with `__call__` and a custom `__repr__`, all combined with `**kwargs`. But it's impossible to know exactly without seeing a code sample of what you want to achieve and what criteria you want it to fulfil.

Comment: I'm going to try and make it work with `eval()`, but I'll look into those too as well. I can try and give a code sample, but I don't think there's room in stack overflow comments.

Comment: Well, [edit] your question…!

Comment: If you want to test whether some binary input equals a binary output, why not actually check that? Converting from a "binary string" to a "list of booleans" and vice versa is *much* more trivial than code generation. You can also directly do binary operations via integers.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi the point of my function is to return the expression, not to test it. I am doing things where I want to get logical expressions. As an ideal, I want to then be able to call that expression.

Comment: Yet calling *does* test the expression, according to your description. And it's not like introspecting a boolean-vector-encoded-in-a-function is any simpler than inspecting a boolean vector.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the purpose of the program. I already know what the results of the expression will be. I'm working backwards from the answer to find the question, essentially. I'd like to be able to call the resulting boolean algebra, that's a bonus, but not the main purpose. This is for electronics application, minimising logic circuits for implementation.

Comment: As an example, I have a truth table that says for the binary input '1101', my output is binary '1', then the function would, for that input, return (A and B and (not C) and D). Now, it does it as a string, which I can then evaluate with `eval()`.

Comment: You could implement a class which takes `'1101'` as input, and which has one method (perhaps even `__str__` or `__repr__`) that returns `'(A and B and (not C) and D'` and another that returns `1`, perhaps `__call__`. Both only need to evaluate the input `'1101'` to get these two different interpretations of it, but it can be represented as one object.

Comment: If you have an answer to your own question then you should post it as an answer so others can use it

Comment: @MatthewBarlowe I didn't know I could do that! Still new to stack exchange. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

With the aid of some people in the comments, I determined that the best way to do get what I was aiming for would be to construct the expression as a string. This could then be evaluated using the `eval()` function, as long as the string was syntactically correct.

```py
def logic_AND_expression(*parameters)
    return ' and '.join(*parameters)

eval(logic_AND_expression('A','B','C','D'),{'A'=True,'B'=False,'C'=True,'D'=True})

False
```